# how i can resolve that in c++ using QT

Tags: c++, xml, qt

```
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(bla bla bla);
QFile file(fileName);
ReadXML Rxml;
Rxml.readXML(file);
```

I get the following compiling error:

```
QFile:QFile(const QFile&) is private in definition of macro 'Q_DISABLE_COPY' within this context use of deleted function 'QFile::QFile(const QFile&)'
```

someone can help me?

Answer (score 3):

You can't copy a QFile.

Refactor your readXML to accept a QFile* or QFile& instead, or a QIODevice* (the most flexible and common option in qt), and pass a pointer or reference.

Comment: I'm learning c++ and i need to read an XML file using GUI (QT in this case) but I don't know how to give the XML file or the XML information to a method in other class..

Comment: Not sure what "read an XML using GUI" means but I did describe how to pass the information to another function. At this point you would benefit from going through a c++ tutorial or two.

Comment: as jason mentioned, you can use it by giving a reference to your method instead of an object.

Comment: like a window with a button then i press the button and i can choose my xml file..
thanks, i will search some videos about the reference..

Comment: If you want to read an XML file as stream you could start wit [this example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtxml-streambookmarks-example.html)